# Formal Logic - Natural deduction: Problem with assumptions about exists-negation

Tags: logic, propositional-logic, natural-deduction

I'm stuck on how to progress with this proof, despite I have tried, I cannot see the next move.

Given this proof without predicate:

[image: Proof]

**So far what I've accomplished:**

[image: My approach]

My idea is, as I can't see any other option using `(-(Sv(P->Q))` as the first assumption in order to introduce a conditional, so the assumption must end in `P ^ -Q ^ -S`. As you can see I have obatined `-Q and -S` but, **how do I proof `P`?**

## SOLUTION:

[image: sol]

Comment: Note that there's no need to add "SOLVED" or anything like that to the title/question, once you mark an answer as accepted, it's done :) Welcome to the site!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is a bit hard to say exactly which introductions you should perform since we don't have your rule set, but I think the over all strategy should be as follows:

From $\neg (S \lor (P \to Q))$ you get $\neg (P \to Q)$.  Since you have $\neg Q$, you should try to introduce $\neg P$ and thus obtain $P \to Q$.  That should be a contradiction and you can conclude $P$.

Comment: Damn now I see it:

Comment: Good!  Nicely done!